# pip got corrupted after uninstalling python packages

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, uninstall, pip

I uninstalled some python packages in ubuntu using `sudo pip uninstall packagename` and after that my pip got corrupted. When I do `pip -V` its showing this

```
   from pip._internal.download import PipSession
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six, urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 118, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

The first thing I did to solve this problem is to reinstall pip itself so I did

```
sudo apt remove python-pip --purge
sudo apt install python-pip
```

But `pip -V` gives the same error. So I then again completely removed pip without reinstalling `sudo apt remove python-pip --purge; sudo apt autoremove`.

Now I have completely purged pip from my system but even after this when I did `pip -V` I am getting same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On taking a look at the error described, this looks like an issue with the `PyOpenSSL` python package. Please follow these steps for resolving this issue (please make sure that the commands are run from a `sudo` prompt):

- `cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`
- `rm -rf OpenSSL`
- `rm -rf /home/<Your Username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL`
- `pip install pyOpenSSL`

If that doesn't work out, run the following (please make sure that the `python3` and `pip3` are installed in your machine):

- `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pyOpenSSL`